# Как выводить сообщение при краше приложения?

Tags: java, android

Видел в некоторых приложениях, при непредвиденной ошибке, уже после закрытия приложения выскакивало диалоговое окно с сообщением и просьбой отправить логи на почту. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Что мешает создать динамический массив(это самое банальное просто), где каждая ячейка - будет строка со стектрейсом.

Места где вы ожидаете непредвиденные ошибки помещаете в `try-catch` , `catch` выдает стректрейс, который вы сохраняете в динамический массив. А в `onDestroy` создаете диалог, который предлагает отправить ошибки Вам - а там передавайте хоть в виде `json` . Костыль конечно, но вопрос довольно общий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой функционал можно получить с помощью библиотеки [`Application Crash Reports for Android`](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) и ей подобных.

Если приложение распространяется через Google Play, то все падения и `ANR` Вашего приложения, можно посмотреть в [Google Play Developer Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6083203) (*если пользователь подтвердил отправку данных о краше*).

А чисто технически, это можно реализовать самому: при возникновении исключения ловите его с помощью `try-catch` и в блоке `catch` реализуете метод отправки логов куда-либо. Другое дело, стоит ли писать велосипед, когда уже все написано...

Comment: А скажите про "если пользователь подтвердил отправку данных о краше", приложение распространяется через Google Play, у самого было несколько падений, в консоли статистика падений и ANR не поменялась

Comment: @user210886, А при падениях Вы нажимали кнопку `Report`?

Comment: Такая кнопка и не вылезала

Comment: @user210886, Странно, если приложение загружено из `Google Play`, то эта кнопка, по идее, должна быть.

Comment: а это не связано с кастомной прошивкой и рут правами?

Comment: @user210886, Точно сказать не могу, но вполне возможно. Gapps вручную прошивали или они уже были в прошивке?