# Как снять и отправить логи при падении приложения на android?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение на android которое я тестирую везде где можно и на некоторых устройствах приложение падает, но этих устройств у меня нету под рукой, и мне соответственно нужно что-бы мне на почту приходили логи ошибки. Я уже задавал два вопроса [Определить причину падения приложения на телефоне android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865066/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-android) //
[Непонятная проблема программы android y xiaomi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/860893/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-android-y-xiaomi). И вот у меня возник закономерный вопрос, что нужно дописать своему приложению что-бы во время падения оно предлагало пользователю отправить логи мне на почту? Как сделать, что-бы эти методы отслеживания логов активировались только в момент падения приложения а не при любом удобном для них (методов) случае. Я буду очень благодарен за любую помощь, советы и само-собой критику от всех кто увидит мой вопрос. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591350/11515

Comment: Crashlytics довольно удобный сервис для этих целей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Честно сказать я не пробовал пока-что реализовать код приведенный в первом ответе, пока никто мне не отвечал, я нашел в сети такой способ:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_login);


        submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendPost();
            }
        });

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
                handleUncaughtException(thread, ex);
            }
        });

    }

    public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
    {
        String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        String message = e.getMessage();
        Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"angoran16@gmail.com"});
        intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MyApp Crash log file");
        intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stackTrace);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // required when starting from Application
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

данный способ позволил мне отправить с проблемного телефона не именно на почту, а через любое приложение имеющее функцию отправки сообщений, телеграмм или gmail. Короче мне этот способ на данный момент помог отправить код ошибки и теперь у меня есть причина падения. Надеюсь мой ответ поможет кому-то еще с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 1):

Я вот такой класс для нашей игры писал:

```
public class LogsSender {

    public static void sendLogs(Activity activity) {
        Log("sendLogs" );

        printInfo();

        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        try {
            String command = String.format("logcat -d -v threadtime *:*");
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String currentLine = null;

            while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (currentLine != null && currentLine.contains(String.valueOf(pid))) {
                    result.append(currentLine);
                    result.append("\n");
                }
            }

            Log(result.toString());

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/email");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"ваша_почта"});
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Logs");
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, result.toString());

            activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail using..."));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void Log(String txt){
        Log.d("unity", txt);
    }

    private static void printInfo(){
        Log("externalMemoryAvailable: " + externalMemoryAvailable());
        if(externalMemoryAvailable()){
            Log("getTotalExternalMemorySize: " + getTotalExternalMemorySize());
            Log("getAvailableExternalMemorySize: " + getAvailableExternalMemorySize());
        }

        Log("getTotalInternalMemorySize: " + getTotalInternalMemorySize());
        Log("getAvailableInternalMemorySize: " + getAvailableInternalMemorySize());
    }

    private static boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
        return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    }

    private static String getAvailableInternalMemorySize() {
        File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
        return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
    }

    private static String getTotalInternalMemorySize() {
        File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
        return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
    }

    private static String getAvailableExternalMemorySize() {
        if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
            long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
            long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocksLong();
            return formatSize(availableBlocks * blockSize);
        } else {
            return "ext not available";
        }
    }

    private static String getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
        if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
            File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
            long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
            long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
            return formatSize(totalBlocks * blockSize);
        } else {
            return "ext not available";
        }
    }

    private static String formatSize(long size) {
        String suffix = null;

        if (size >= 1024) {
            suffix = "KB";
            size /= 1024;
            if (size >= 1024) {
                suffix = "MB";
                size /= 1024;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder resultBuffer = new StringBuilder(Long.toString(size));

        int commaOffset = resultBuffer.length() - 3;
        while (commaOffset > 0) {
            resultBuffer.insert(commaOffset, ',');
            commaOffset -= 3;
        }

        if (suffix != null) resultBuffer.append(suffix);
        return resultBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Если вам нужно именно логи краша, то код `LoginActivity`, который вызывает краш, можете завернуть в `try {} catch{}`, в `catch` вывести в лог стектрейс исключения, а потом вызвать `LogsSender.sendLogs`. Откроется окно с выбором почтового клиента, автоматически все поля будут занесены после выбора клиента. Человеку останется только кнопку "Отправить" нажать.